# Angularjs: element.bind('click') event works but element.bind('load') event not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am new to angularjs, I am trying to execute some function once a div got loaded.

## app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.directive('orientable', function () {       
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {   

            element.bind("load" , function(e){ 
                            alert('hiii1');
                  }
                });
        }
     }
});
```

## index.html

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <p orientable>
        Hiii
     </p>
</div>
```

## My requirement

I need element 'p' should bind with a function once it got loaded. Here in my code alert message not showing up, so 'p' element not bind to 'load'. But if I change the code in app.js from **'element.bind("load" , function(e){'** to **'element.bind("click" , function(e){ '**, the 'p' element got bind with click event, hence when I click on the 'p' element alert message appears. How I will make my 'p' element bind to 'load' event.

Comment: Why don't you execute what you want in link function directly? Why do you need `element.bind('load')`?

Comment: This example is just for testing. I have another example where i need to call the custom directive recursively, where the more dynamic div's get loaded. How do I handle the dynamic loaded div's?? I need 'element.bind('load')' for that right. There I need to call some function when the dynamic div's got added.

Comment: What I want is 'onload' functionality. How to use that one in angularjs??

Answer (score 0):

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {   

    element.bind("load" , function(e){ 
                    alert('hiii1');
          }
        });
}
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-link-

> It is executed after the template has been cloned.

So you're binding a load event to an element that has already been loaded.

The `onLoad` function you want **IS** the `link` function.

Comment: Hey am using the same code as you posted. But its not working

Comment: @SumanthUdupa it is your code. I repeated it in my answer so that it's clear that you're setting up a load event when the element is already loaded... The load event that you want is the link function.